# JSON.NET JObject - how do I get value from this nested JSON structure

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonpath, jpath

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "client_id": "26075235",
    "client_version": "1.0.0",
    "event": "app.uninstall",
    "timestamp": 1478741247,
    "data": {
        "user_id": "62581379",
        "site_id": "837771289247593785",
        "platform_app_id": "26075235"
    }
}
```

I parse it into a JSON.NET JObject and I can successfully access the first level of values using e.g. `(string)RequestBody.SelectToken("client_id")`

How do I access the value of "user_id" **using a JPath expression** (or by accessing a child object of the JSON.NET JObject)?  This doesn't work:

```
(string)RequestBody.SelectToken("data[0].user_id")
```

and I can't do this to parse the 'data' part of the JSON:

```
JObject RequestBodyData = JObject.Parse((string)RequestBody.SelectToken("data"));
```

as the compiler seems to recognise `RequestBody.SelectToken("data")` as an object (I get the error 'Can not parse object into string')

and I don't want to parse the original JSON into a custom C# object as I'm developing a solution that needs to be able to generically parse JSON into a JObject (or any other type of generic object for handling JSON), so it can be parsed in a relatively consistent way.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`SelectToken("data[0].user_id")` doesn't work because there isn't an array in your JSON.  You should use `SelectToken("data.user_id")` instead.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/K0X4ht

Comment: This still works nicely in 2022, and the dotnetfiddle made it very simple to test on my weird data.