# How can I get the value from a nested property in JObject

Tags: .net, json.net

I have the following JObject:

```
jObject = {
  "abertura": "09/06/2017",
  "situacao": "ATIVA",
  "tipo": "MATRIZ",
  "nome": "11CARE SERVICOS DE SAUDE LTDA",
  "fantasia": "11CARE",
  "porte": "EMPRESA DE PEQUENO PORTE",
  "natureza_juridica": "206-2 - Sociedade Empresária Limitada",
  "qsa": [{
    "nome": "SANTA RITA PARTICIPACOES E INVESTIMENTOS LTDA",
    "qual": "22-Sócio",
    "nome_rep_legal": "PRISCILA CARLA ALBANIT",
    "qual_rep_legal": "05-Administrador"
  }, {
    "nome": "PRISCILA CARLA ALBANIT",
    "qual": "05-Administrador"
  }]
}
```

I can get values from the properties like this:

```
var abertura = jObject.GetValue("abertura").ToString()
```

but how can I get the value from a nested property, I want to set the value from property "nome" inside "qsa" in a new variable, I've tried the following:

```
var nome = jObject.GetValue("qsa").GetValue("nome")
```

but it does not work, anyone can help?

Comment: You can use `SelectTokens` as shown in [JSON.NET JObject - how do I get value from this nested JSON structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40538001/3744182) Or you can chain indexers as shown in [Json.NET get nested jToken value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42300875/3744182).  In fact this looks like a duplicate of those two, agree?

Comment: `qsa` is a `JArray` so you need to iterate through it first. Is there any reason you are using `JToken` anyway, why not use real classes with properties?

Comment: yes, agreed, I solved my problem using index, in fact I realized that I will just need the first index of the list , thank you guys